# Using unicode characters in gwt checkbox label

Tags: gwt, unicode

How can I put a unicode character in the label(constructor) of a gwt checkbox. if I put the character in, gwt escapes the & and I end up with &#235; in the label of the checkbox instead of ë.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unicode characters in Java String literals follow a special [syntax](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Syntax/Unicode_Escape_Sequences).

In your case, you could write it like this:

```
new CheckBox("H\u00ebllo")
```

The code for "ë" is `00eb` - you can use e.g. [this table](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/). By the way, 00eb<sub>hexadecimal</sub> = 235<sub>decimal</sub>

Another possibility is to save your Java files as UTF-8. Then you can write your literals without escaping for these characters. This however also requires you to set the compiler option `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`. Many IDEs do this automatically, if you set the encoding preference for the file to UTF-8.

---

Another important factor is that you should set the charset of your HTML page correctly (usually UTF-8):

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```